# Deleting records in yiiframework model by column

Tags: php, yii

How can I delete records in yiiframework when users logged-out in Whosloggedin model by column username?

table - whosloggedin

```
CREATE TABLE `erc_whosloggedin` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `complete_name` varchar(95) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I Have tried something like this

```
    $whosloggedin=Whosloggedin::model()->find($users->username); 
    $whosloggedin->delete();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters passed to find function is wrong.

In Find function we have to pass $condition & $params parameters, by default $condition is an empty & $params is an empty array.

```
find($condition='',$params=array())
```

You solution would be:

```
$whosloggedin=Whosloggedin::model()->find('username=:username',array(':username'=>$users->username) ); 
$whosloggedin->delete();
```

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested but it seems the parameter $users->username is null <br/>class SiteController extends Controller
{<br/>public function actionLogout()
 {
  Yii::app()->user->logout();
        
$user=Users::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?',array(strtolower($this->username)));
        
$whosloggedin = Whosloggedin::model()->find('username=:username',array(':username'=>$users->username) ); 
$whosloggedin->delete();

  $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
 }

Comment: $this->username will not be available after Yii::app()->user->logout();. Store it in another variable before logout than pass it to find function for Users model.

Answer (score 0):

check out `beforeLogout()` and `afterLogout()` methods of the `CWebUser` class.

You can override them and do your work there.
Not sure about `afterLogout()` but surely in `beforeLogout()` there should still be a reference to the username.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#afterLogout-detail

**Also (and on a sidenote):**

you would probably also want to query the user table for users that haven't logged out but whos session timed out.

**About finding the user:**

use `findByAttributes()` for a single or `findAllByAttributes()` for more than 1 row.

```
$user = Whosloggedin::model()->findByAttributes(array(
    'username' => Yii->app()->user->name,
));
```